# intelliJ speed up tool tip appearance

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

I'm new to intelliJ and sometimes like to use the "tool tips" (or whatever the kids are calling it these days - the thing that pops up when your mouse hovers over it) to find out what the different buttons do.

Annoyingly, sometimes i have to wait more than a heartbeat for the tool tip to appear. Is it possible to edit the speed with which said tips appear in intelliJ when I hover my mouse over a tool-tip-enabled item?

**EDIT** i am running 12.0.1 - one solution below is for 12.1.3+ (as noted in the comments), any ideas for below 12.1.3

Comment: I added a "solution" for pre 12.1.3. Edit the `idea.vmoptions` file.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is a setting in the `Settings` window.

[image]

---

**Edit**

This seems to be available from version 12.1.3 only.

You can although edit the `idea.vmoptions` file and add a line like this at the end:

```
-Dide.tooltip.initialDelay=200
```

This makes the tooltip appear much faster (at least in some areas). Try by hovering on a tab in the editor pane. It will pop up very fast. Then close IntelliJ and change the value to 20000 and try again. As you will notice it will take 20 seconds (as expected).

For example try hovering over buttons as you describe in your question. By setting the delay to a very low value the tooltip appears immediately.

Comment: aw, i am on 12.0.1 and i don't have that bit. I have the override above and the transperance below, but in mine there is nothing inbetween them

Comment: @bharal It looks like this *feature* was first introduced in 12.1.3. You'll have to upgrade. http://www.bytespring.com/blog/death-intellij-tooltips

Comment: nice, but now if i move it around - ok, i mean, now i am just quibbling - but now if i get one tooltip, but then lok at the one next to it, the first tooltip hangs around for a while before i can see the new tooltip. I fiddled with ide.tooltip.dismissDelay (where can i get the full list?) but that just makes the tool tip disappear regardless of if the mouse moved or not!

Comment: I wish the tooltip delay applied to the debugger because it's always flashing like crazy when I move my mouse over the Variables area.

Comment: @BrianGordon You can go to `Settings -> Debugger -> Data Views`. There you have an option called `Value tooltips delay (ms)` that can can be updated with a longer delay.