# Tooltips go away too fast in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I find the tooltips to be quite helpful, except for the fact that they tend to vanish a lot faster than I can read through the longer ones. I've already set them up to [appear faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17086989/intellij-speed-up-tool-tip-appearance). Is it possible to also make them stick around longer, ideally until I move the mouse again?